# Unable to execute pig scripts using Azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

This is my Pig script

```
$QueryString = "A =  load 'wasb://$containername@$StorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/table1' using PigStorage(',') as (col1 chararray,col2 chararray,col3 chararray,col4 chararray,col5 chararray,col6 chararray,col7 int,col8 int);" +
"user_list = foreach A GENERATE $0;" +
"unique_user = DISTINCT user_list;" +
"unique_users_group = GROUP unique_user ALL;" +
"uu_count = FOREACH unique_users_group GENERATE COUNT(unique_user);" +
"DUMP uu_count;"
```

i get this error when i execute above pig script

```
'2015-04-14 23:17:55,177 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <line 1, column 166>  mismatched input 'chararray' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
Failed to parse: <line 1, column 166>  mismatched input 'chararray' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:241)
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1678)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1411)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:344)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:369)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:355)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:769)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:509)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
2015-04-14 23:17:55,177 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt -   ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 166>  mismatched input 'chararray' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

I edited the LOAD statement like this and the rest of the script is same

```
$QueryString = "A =  load 'wasb://$containername@$StorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/table1';" +
```

the error i get now is

```
2015-04-14 23:23:00,117 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <line 1, column 162>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near ';'
Failed to parse: <line 1, column 162>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near ';'
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:241)
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1678)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1411)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:344)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:369)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:355)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:769)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:509)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
2015-04-14 23:23:00,132 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 162>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near ';'
Details at logfile: C:\apps\dist\hadoop-2.4.0.2.1.9.0-2196\logs\pig_1429053777602.log
```

I don't understand what the error is. Can you someone help me with executing this query on windows powershell(i am using windows powershell ISE, so i can edit the queries)

[image: terminal execution]

Comment: Can you show how you executing the script? Command line?

Comment: @JanChrbolka i added a picture of the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is at this statement `user_list = foreach A GENERATE $0;`. PowerShell is interpreting **$0** as a parameter, and since it is not defined PowerShell is substituting an empty string. You can define a parameter in the script like `$0 = '$0';` or just escape the **$** like:

```
user_list = foreach A GENERATE `$0;
```

*PowerShell uses the ` (backtick, next to the '1' key) as an escape character for double-quoted strings.*

so the script can look like:

```
$0 = '$0';
$QueryString = "A =  load 'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/table1' using PigStorage(',') as (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) ;"+
"user_list = foreach A GENERATE $0;" +
"unique_user = DISTINCT user_list;" +
"unique_users_group = GROUP unique_user ALL;" +
"uu_count = FOREACH unique_users_group GENERATE COUNT(unique_user);" +
"DUMP uu_count;"
```

or

```
$QueryString = "A =  load 'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/table1' using PigStorage(',') as (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) ;"+
"user_list = foreach A GENERATE `$0;" +
"unique_user = DISTINCT user_list;" +
"unique_users_group = GROUP unique_user ALL;" +
"uu_count = FOREACH unique_users_group GENERATE COUNT(unique_user);" +
"DUMP uu_count;"
```